# jquery ui datepicker selected year should be on top

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker, range

jquery ui datepicker selected year  should be on top, in my case 2020 is selected year, and I want it on top of dropdown list.
[image]

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking how to modify the library?

Comment: You might consider going with native date inputs. jQueryUI hasn't been in development for many years and, unless you need to support IE, JavaScript datepickers aren't really necessary.

Comment: What would be the point of that, by the way?

Comment: Do you want to reverse the year range list?

Comment: I want selected year(2020 in picture) on top of dropdown list (where 2001 is placed).